# Where is the location of Google Drive folder in Android phone?

Tags: files, google-drive

I'm looking for the location of the Google Drive folder in an Android phone, Realme V3 5G.

I expect the location to be something like `\android\data\com.google.android.apps.books`.

Where is it?

Answer (score 4):

It's in the hidden partition `/data` which you cannot access without root permissions.

Here's the path: `/data/data/com.google.android.apps.docs/files`.

Comment: No: "The android google drive location is com.google.android.apps.docs, and which is located inside internal storage >> android >> data.

However, downloaded files from the Google drive are not stored inside this folder, and the truth is that the folder is usually empty." ... "When you download any of the uploaded files from your Google drive account, it goes straight to the download folder. This usually confuses some users especially those using android phone cause the drive has a data folder inside android folder." [here](https://gadgetroyale.com/google-drive-files-stored-on-android/)